# How to write a clear and elegant code for a strategy pattern based application?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am writing an application to compose musical freizes, but I am a little worried about the structure of classes and interfaces within the code. Here there are the signatures of some classes I wrote:

```
Interface IGuidoFormattable
Class Note : IGuidoFormattable, ICloneable
Class Pause : IGuidoFormattable, ICloneable
Class Chord : List<Note>, IGuidoFormattable, ICloneable
Class Key : IGuidoFormattable, ICloneable
Class Tempo : IGuidoFormattable, ICloneable
Class Meter : IGuidoFormattable, ICloneable
Class FretPiece : List<IGuidoFormattable>, ICloneable
Class Fret : List<FretPiece>
```

FretPiece represents a muscial phrase, a piece of the complete freize. It exposes as properties Key, Tempo and Meter, which are homonym with their types. More phrases put together create a freize, respresented by the Fret class. Every element within a single phrase must be formattable in accordance with the GUIDO standard notation, hence it has to implement the IGuidoFormattable interface.
In another namespace, some mutation classes are defined and they all inherit from one of the two abstract classes:

```
Class FretMutation
Class LambdaFretMutation : FretMutation
```

Finally, there exists a class called FretMutationGenerator which has the only task of applying selected mutations to a music theme and output the entire freize as an instance of Fret class.

FretPiece must be able to contain several different elements (notes, pauses and chords in this case), which nonetheless must satisfy two constraints: they have to be formattable with GUIDO notation and therefore transformed into meaningful strings; they have to be cloneable. In the code as it is now, every class implements ICloneable, but syntax and semantics of current code do not grant that all members of the collection are cloneable. I need to find a way to express both constraint without applying inheritance to IGuidoFormattable and preferably without defining a Clone method in the IGuidoFormattable interface.

Second, and most important, problem. FretMutation defines an abstract method, "Apply", that has to be overridden in every derived class. Therefore, any mutation class defines its own version of this method, which has the following signature:

```
FretPiece Apply(FretPiece originalTheme)
```

It accepts as input a FretPiece and outputs a copy of that object, mutated according to all other parameters specified as members of the class. I think that this is an implementation of the strategy pattern. However, only becase of the fact that this method creats a copy of the input, it means that the argument itself (and therefore all its members) must be cloneable.
In addition, FretPiece is declared as a list of IGuidoFormattable, but every mutation class behaves differently from the others and may act on notes, pauses or chord, accordingly: this means that I need to check every element's type, and write a different code for each type with "a lot" (indeed, 3 at most) if statements. And this seems to me very little object oriented.

How can I arrange classes and interface in a way that all become more object oriented and less dependent on assumptions and type-checking?

Comment: Properly answering this question requires understanding how these types are all connected (i.e., is a Chord simply a set of Notes, etc.).  Have you taken a look at using [GUIDOLib](http://guidolib.sourceforge.net/) (C++)?  At the least, you might be able to use it to see how to organize your classes.

Comment: I can't read music at all but I think there are huge conceptual differences between notes-, pause , chords and tempo (I have no idea what a Key could be) Notes, pause and chard are content and tempo is a modifier of that content. So a node can be influenced by tempo but not tempo itself cannot be influenced by note. I believe you should rethink your class structure a bit to reflect this.

Comment: You maybe have misunderstood what I meant, since I intentionally provided almost no code. Tempo specifies the number of beats per minute and the duration digure which represents one beat. Key is the tonality of the compositiong (ex. C Major, G Minor, ...). Meter indicates the time signature. Meter, Tempo and Key are properties of the FretPiece class, representing a musical phrase. Notes, pauses and chords are element within this phrase. A chord is here represented as a simple list of notes. All functions for formatting to GUIDO notation and converting it into a MIDI file are already written.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Key, Tempo and Meter must implement the IGuidoFormattable interface since I have to write those information in the notation file. Here it is an example: {[\key<2> \meter<"4/4"> \tempo<"","1/4=120"> a1*1/8 b1*178 c#1*1/4 ]} However, even if they implement this interface they WON'T be included as elements in the FretPiece collection. This was a thing I didn't notice before. This should be avoided as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to find a way to express both
>   constraint without applying
>   inheritance to IGuidoFormattable and
>   preferably without defining a Clone
>   method in the IGuidoFormattable
>   interface

What about the third option?

```
public interface ICloneableAndGuidoFormattable : IGuidoFormattable, ICloneable { }
```

Then your FretPiece is List Of ICloneableAndGuidoFormattable

If not that, you could try such a construct:

```
public interface ICloneable<T>
{
  T Clone();
}

public class FretPiece : IEnumerable<IFormattable>, ICloneable<FretPiece>
{
    private List<IFormattable> items = new List<IFormattable>();

    public void Add<T>(T value) where T : IFormattable, ICloneable<IFormattable>
    {
        items.Add(value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<IFormattable> GetEnumerator()
    {
        items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public FretPiece Clone()
    {
        return new FretPiece { items = new List<IFormattable>(
            items.Cast<ICloneable<IFormattable>>().Select(c=>c.Clone()))
        };
    }
}
```

And somewhere else e.g. on your mutator:

```
public T Apply<T>(T fretPiece) where T : IEnumerable<IFormattable>, ICloneable<T> ( ...)
```

This would ensure that you can only add items implementing both interfaces. the enumeration only assumes that IFormattables are returned. This would allow you inside the cast to safely cast to ICloneable since it must have passed the type constraint on "Add". You can see the implementation of clone. Even though you have a cast there it is safe unless somebody fiddles with `items` based on reflection ;)

Comment: I wrote "I need to find a way to express both constraint without applying inheritance to IGuidoFormattable", but your second solution seems to work pretty well as I have intended. What could you say about the most important matter of mutations? I.e. how can I write a code for Apply method without checking the type of each item of the collection (assumed it is cloneable and formattable, anyway)?

Comment: Not sure but Apply may also be defined generic and define parameter constraints. Hence, the class above may also implement ICloneable<T>, see update of my answer, renamed Foo, and let it implement interface

Comment: In will not work. Only at runtime I know the type of element on which I am using Apply, hence I cannot declare generics type before compilation. But I think I found a discrete solution in the meantime. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would make several of them immutable. That way you don't need to clone them anymore. A note is always the same note, regardless of where it appears. So it feels natural to make it immutable.

For example Note,Pause,Chord seem like they would work well as immutable types. Most of your other class names are gibberish to me since I don't know enough about musical theory, so I don't know which of them could be immutable too.

Comment: Nope. Immutable objects are exluded. For example, you could have a music sheet with several notes printed onto it: we can say that the first and the fifth notes are both B flat of central octave, but one is the first note of the piece and lasts 1/4 (and maybe it is staccato), and the latter is the fifth and lasts, say, 1/8 and is dotted. Note names are immutable, but notes aren't. Thanks for the answer, anyway.

Comment: @Totem What stops you from making a note consist of several properties, one for the length and one for the frequency and perhaps one for the instrument? IMO the note doesn't need to know if it's the fifth note in the piece, or the first or both at the same time.

Comment: Infact the note doesn't know and doesn't need to know (and I would add it must also not know). It's its position within the piece that makes difference. Indeed, you are right, I could incapsulate the information of note name, accidentals and octave in one immutable-like class itself. But still a note can have duration, dots, expressions (staccato, legato, marcato, etc...) and much more properties that are its own and does not depend on its pitch and therefore a immutable Note class is logically impossible.